# Get 302 redirect by virtual waiting room like queue-it using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I just created a spider to crawl a webpage using Scrapy. And I found the request sending to the [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) was redireted to queue.mydomain.com (by https://queue-it.com/) and got 404 response. I try to switch user-agent, but it doesn't work. Can anybody guide me how to bypass the virtual waiting room?

Comment: Better you add some of your code implementation so it can be easier to fix.

Comment: maybe page uses `JavaScript` but `Scrapy` can't run `JavaScript` and it would need extension to uses [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or `splash` to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. ie. [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium), [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

Comment: hey and how you now bypass it?